# Find missing sequence number in a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Let suppose my database data structure is like that

```
ShopId   Transaction

001       1.000    
001       2.000
001       3.000
002       1.000
002       2.000
002       3.000
```

Now it is might possible that some transaction are missing let suppose

```
002       4.000
002       6.000
```

In above table 5.000 transaction of table is missing.

**I want to write a query that find the missing sequence number like above in my database.**

So my query will return result

```
   shopid     transaction
   002       5.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of missing transactions per `ShopId`:

```
  SELECT ShopId
       , count(*) 
           - max([Transaction])
           + min([Transaction])
           - 1 as MissingTranCount
    FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ShopId
```

To get the missing transactions:

1.[Generate table #numbers](http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/t-sql/archive/2007/11/06/2693.aspx)

2.Generate #shops:

```
  SELECT ShopId as id
    into #shops
    FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ShopId
  HAVING count(*) 
           - max([Transaction])
           + min([Transaction])
           - 1 > 0
```

3.Get the missing transactions:

```
  SELECT id
       , number
    FROM #numbers
   cross join #shops shops
   WHERE exists (SELECT 1
                   FROM yourtable
                  WHERE ShopId = id
                    and number < [Transaction]
                )
     and exists (SELECT 1
                   FROM yourtable
                  WHERE ShopId = id
                    and number > [Transaction]
                )
     and not exists (SELECT 1
                       FROM yourtable
                      WHERE ShopId = id
                        and number = [Transaction]
                )
```